# Opencv: Arranging sample vectors from calcOpticalFlowFarneback for kmeans - "error:samples was not declared in this scope"

Tags: opencv, k-means, opticalflow

I'm trying to use optical flow to detect objects (people, cars) from a still camera and then eventually get other info from them. I'm getting stuck with moving the optical flow vectors into an array of sample vectors that kmeans is happy with.

Here's me code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

Mat img,labels, original,flow, centres;
UMat prevgray, flowUmat, gray;

int count=0,clusterCount=4, size, loop=0, val=0.1, k=4;

VideoCapture cap("cars.avi");
if(!cap.isOpened())
{
    printf("Error 404: no video found\n");
    return 0;
}
else printf("Capture from file successfull!!\n");
///forever loop
for(;;) {
cap >>img;
if (!cap.grab())
{
    cout << "\n Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
    if(waitKey(0)==27){break;}
}
img.copyTo(original);
cvtColor(img, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
//================
///     FLOW
//================
if (prevgray.empty() == false ) {
    calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray,gray,flowUmat, 0.4,1,50,2,5,1.2,0); //0.5,3,21,20,5,1.1
    flowUmat.copyTo(flow);

    //arranging sample vectors
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> samples (flowUmat.rows*flowUmat.cols);
    int n=0;
    for( int y=0; y<flowUmat.rows; y++){
        for (int x=0;x<flowUmat.cols;x++){
            const Point2f& flowatxy=flow.at<Point2f>(y,x);
            line(original, Point(x,y), Point(cvRound(x+flowatxy.x*4), cvRound(y+flowatxy.y*4)), Scalar(0,255,0));
            circle(original, Point(x,y), 0.1, Scalar(0,0,0),-1);
            samples[n++] = flow.at<cv::Point2f>(y,x);
        }
    }
gray.copyTo(prevgray);
}
else
    img.copyTo(prevgray);

///PROBLEM AREA
kmeans(samples, k, labels, TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS+TermCriteria::COUNT,10,1.0),3,KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,centres);

waitKey(1);
std::swap(prevgray, gray);
loop++;
}
return 0;
}
```

The error it returns reads "error: ‘samples’ was not declared in this scope".

I'm relatively bad at coding, so any help would be appreciated.